# ¿Cómo obtener acceso a la conexión mediante PDO?

Tags: php, pdo

viendo varios tutoriales hay algunas cosas que no me han quedado claras de las consultas preparadas y PDO una de esas dudas es la siguiente: Tengo mi archivo conexion.php y por ejemplo deseo desarrollar una consulta preparada en otro archivo llamado consultarlogin.php en donde verifico si ya existe un usuario en la base de datos, la pregunta es la siguiente ¿cada vez que genere un archivo nuevo con consultas preparadas debo reescribir la conexión a la base de datos?

Es decir ¿tengo que siempre declarar la variable que contiene el objeto de la conexión?

```
$conexion = new PDO('mysql:db=lacorotera;host=localhost', 'root', '', $arrOptions);
```

ó ¿se podría incluir o requerir al archivo conexion.php y listo?

Gracias de Antemano.

```
   <?php 
class Conexion{

   protected $conexion;

   public function Conexion(){
  $arrOptions = array(
   PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => FALSE, 
   PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, 
   PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'"
);

try {

   $this->conexion= new PDO('mysql:db=lacorotera;host=localhost', 'root', '', $arrOptions);
   return $this->conexion;
        
} catch (Exception $e) {

   echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage() . " producido en la línea: " . $e->getLine();

}finally{

  }
 }
}
?>
```

Comment: Hola BetaM muchas gracias por responder, pues la verdad es que no responde a mi pregunta, más allá de explicar la diferencia de cada una de estas llamadas mi pregunta se basa especificamente en si se debe declarar la variable que contiene el objeto conexión cuando se hacen consultas preparadas con código orientado a objetos ó si se puede llamar al archivo que contiene la conexión y mi pregunta la hago es porque los tutoriales que he visto de PDO declaran siempre la variable con el objeto y debajo desarrollan la consulta entonces no sé si se puede hacer de ambas formas

Comment: Ya, es que al inicio fue confusa pero ya te entendí

Comment: De cualquier manera tendrás que agregar una línea, ya sea con `global`, `require` o `new`. Mientras encapsules los parámetros en un solo lugar y no crees mas de una conexión por petición, prácticamente cualquier solución se justifica.

Answer (score 1):

A mi parecer tienes algunas cosas de tu código mal enfocadas, las expongo en los siguientes comentarios:

- *Parece* que estás tratando de declarar un método *constructor* dentro de la clase con la siguiente sintaxis:

  ```
  public function Conexion(){
  ```

Pero lo mismo no es correcto por la siguiente razón:

Los métodos constructores en PHP se declaran con la sintaxis de [**`__construct()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.decon.php#language.oop5.decon.constructor)

Los métodos nos ayudan a agrupar acciones y poder si es necesario retornar el resultado de las mismas, pero lo estás dejando únicamente con un *array* de atributos

Ahora si directamente dentro de la instancia de PDO estás pasando los valores de tu conexión entonces esta demás considerar en este momento un *constructor* de la clase

- Luego de eso tienes una sintaxis de *`try catch`* dentro del contexto directo de la clase, lo cual te debería estar retornando un error como el siguiente:

> Sintax error, unexpected T_TRY expecting T_FUNCTION or T_CONST

Luego entonces dicho *`try catch`* debería estar dentro de un método

Entonces tu código puede quedar así:

```
<?php 
class Conexion
{

   protected $conexion;

   public function conexion()
    {
          $arrOptions = array(
                               PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => FALSE, 
                               PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, 
                               PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'",
                        );

        try {
                $this->conexion= new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=lacorotera', 'root', '', $arrOptions);        
        } catch (Exception $e) {

           echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage() . " producido en la línea: " . $e->getLine();

        }
        return $this->conexion;
    }
}
```

Entonces ahora puedes ocupar tu conexión de al menos 3 formas:

- Que las clases que la requieran hereden de conexión (*puede que en ciertos casos no sea la mejor opción*)
- Inyectar clase y objeto al método donde planeas usar la conexión
- En la o las clases donde la requieras declares la instancia de la misma para poder emplear dicho objeto resultante, anexo para este punto un ejemplo (*con poco de sintaxis de [PHP 7](https://www.php.net/manual/es/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.return-type-declarations), [PHP 7.4](https://www.php.net/manual/es/migration74.new-features.php#migration74.new-features.core.typed-properties) y de [PHP 8](https://www.php.net/releases/8.0/en.php#union-types)*):

  ```
    <?php 

    class Conexion
    {
        public function conectadoAlServidor(): object|null
        {
           return (object)["valor" => "Conectado"];
        }
    }

    class Modelo
    {
        public object $empleaConexion;

        public function procesaConsulta(): object|null 
        {
            $this->empleaConexion = new Conexion();

            return $this->empleaConexion->conectadoAlServidor();
        }
    }

    var_dump((new Modelo())->procesaConsulta());
  ```

Dando como salida:

```
object(stdClass)#3 (1) {
  ["valor"]=>
  string(9) "Conectado"
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder. Ahora bien, supongamos que no quiero usar clases sino que quiero hacer un archivo conexión igual usando PDO, ¿podría por ejemplo usar include "conexion.php"; sin necesidad de declarar igual la línea $conexion = new PDO('mysql:db=lacorotera;host=localhost', 'root', ''");?

Comment: Si no ocupas clases y la conexión no esta dentro de un método entonces con hacer un requerimiento de la conexión donde la ocuparás te dará disponibilidad de la misma y ya solo ocupas la variable que la contiene, no tiene sentido alguno que hagas lo último que mencionas pues la estaría **redeclarando**